# Show that this sequence of events is independent (b-adic expansions)

Tags: probability-theory, independence

The exercise reads:

Let $\Omega:=[0,1[$, $\mathcal{A}:=\Omega\cap \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $P:=\lambda_{\Omega}$ (Lebesgue measure on $\Omega$). Let $b\in\mathbb{N}$ with $b\geq 2$ and $\varepsilon \in \{0,\dots,b-1\}$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let

$$A_n:=\bigcup_{k=0}^{b^{n-1}-1}\bigg[ \frac{kb+\varepsilon}{b^n}, \frac{kb+\varepsilon+1}{b^n} \bigg[$$

Show that this sequence of events is independent by showing that

$$P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_n})=\frac{1}{b}P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_{n-1}}) \hspace{1cm}  $$ for every finite set of distinct natural numbers $i_1,\dots,i_n$.

A few examples convinced me that this is true but how to prove it? Any ideas how to proceed?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: What is $\varepsilon$?

Comment: @LostStatistician Sorry I forgot to mention $\varepsilon$ is an integer between $0$ and $b-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add a bit of notation to write
$$
A_{i, \varepsilon} = \cup_{k=0}^{b^{i-1}-1} \left[ \frac{kb+\varepsilon}{b^i},\frac{kb+\varepsilon+1}{b^i} \right) =: \cup_{k=0}^{b^{i-1}-1} A_{i,\varepsilon}^{(k)}. 
$$

Evidently
$$
P(A_{i,\varepsilon} ) = \sum_{i=0}^{b^{i-1}-1} \frac{1}{b^i} = \frac{1}{b}, 
$$
for each $i$. We also see that for each $i$,
$$
\cup_{\varepsilon=1}^{b-1} A_{i,\varepsilon}= [0,1). 
$$

Now fix $\varepsilon_0 \in \{0,...,b-1\}$. We wish to show that for all natural numbers $i_1< \cdots < i_n$

$$
P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_n,\varepsilon_0}) = \frac{1}{b}P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0}).
$$
According to the above
$$
P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0}) = \sum_{\varepsilon=0}^{b-1} P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon} ) 
$$

Now the aim is to show that

$P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon} )  = P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon'} ) $ for all $\varepsilon,\varepsilon'$. The reason this holds is that for $j > i$, either
$$\cup_{\varepsilon=0}^{b-1} A_{j,\varepsilon}^{(r)} \subset A_{i,\varepsilon'}^{(k)}$$
or
$$
\left[ \cup_{\varepsilon=0}^{b-1} A_{j,\varepsilon}^{(r)}\right] \cap A_{i,\varepsilon'}^{(k)} = \emptyset. 
$$
This is a straightforward calculation, and also describes the essence of why this result is true-- the intervals are $A_{j,\varepsilon}^{(r)}$ are nested and maintain their relative size within eachother for increasing $j$. Notice that this implies that for any $\varepsilon$, $P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon} )$ reduces down to a sum of the probabilities of intervals of the form $A_{i_n,\varepsilon}^{(k)}$, namely the sum over those intervals that intersect $ A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0}$. Since those by the above must coincide in a 1-1 correspondence with the intervals $A_{i_n,\varepsilon'}^{(k)}$ for all other $\varepsilon' \in \{0,...,b-1\}$ that intersect $A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0}$, we must have

$$P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon} )  = P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon'} ) $$
as needed. Hence

$$
P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0}) = b P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon_0} ). 
$$

Comment: I followed until "The reason this holds is that..." I don't see why this proves the result $P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon} )  = P(A_{i_1,\varepsilon_0}\cap \cdots \cap A_{i_{n-1},\varepsilon_0} \cap A_{i_{n},\varepsilon'} )$. Could you expand on that?

Comment: I added some more details. I'm not providing the details as to why you must have that all of the smallest intervals are either contained in or are disjoint from a larger interval-- but this is a fairly straightforward calculation.

Comment: I tried to understand why this dichotomy holds and I came up with the following argument below. What do you think?

Comment: Looks good! It again captures the main point that the intervals are nested and maintain their relative size within each other.

Answer (score 0):

To show independence we may assume WLOG that $i_1< \dots<i_n$. For each $n$ consider the grid of points in $[0,1]$ defined by

$$P_n:=\bigg\{\frac{k}{b^n}:k=0,1,\dots,b^n\bigg\}$$

We see that $P_{n}\subset P_{n+1}$, i.e. the grids are getting finer when $n$ gets larger. Each grid $P_{n}$ determines a set of $b^n$ half-open disjoint intervals in $[0,1)$ of the form $I^k_n=[\frac{k}{b^n},\frac{k+1}{b^n})$ $k=0,1,\dots,b^n-1$. If we divide these intervals into $b^{n-1}$ disjoint groups of $b$ intervals from left to right, then we see that $A_n$ is formed by selecting the $(\varepsilon+1)$th interval  in each group. Hence each $A_n$ is the disjoint union of $b^{n-1}$ intervals of length $1/b^n$, and therefore has measure $1/b$.

What happens if we intersect $A_{i_1}$ and $A_{i_2}$ with $i_1<i_2$? Each of the $b^{i_1-1}$ half-open intervals of $A_{i_1}$ will be sub-divided into $b^{i_2-i_1}$ half-open intervals by the points in $P_{i_2}$, and $A_{i_2}$ selects one interval per group of $b$ such sub-intervals. So the result is a disjoint union of $b^{i_1-1} \cdot b^{i_2-i_1-1}=b^{i_2-2}$ half-open intervals of the form $[\frac{k}{b^{i_2}},\frac{k+1}{b^{i_2}})$.

If we intersect $A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}$ with some $A_{i_3}$ with $i_1<i_2<i_3$, then the same reasoning gives that $A_{i_1}\cap A_{i_2}\cap A_{i_3}$ is a disjoint union of $b^{i_2-2} \cdot b^{i_3-i_2-1}=b^{i_3-3}$ half-open intervals of the form $[\frac{k}{b^{i_3}},\frac{k+1}{b^{i_3}})$.

Inductively we get that $A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_n}$ is a disjoint union of $b^{i_n-n}$ half-open intervals of the form $[\frac{k}{b^{i_n}},\frac{k+1}{b^{i_n}})$. Therefore the formula $$P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_n})=\frac{1}{b}P(A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_{n-1}}) $$ is verified for $i_1< \dots<i_n$. Then induction gives us independence.